# How do i keep my player in pygame from going off of the screen

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

So i've been working lately on some 2D game for my school's final project...
And i needed to make my player or the controlled object so it doesn't go off of the screen/window

I've only managed to make the right and the buttom side of the screen

Here is the entire code

**Thanks to whoever can help!**

```
import pygame
import os
from pygame import draw
pygame.font.init()


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello, World!")

FPS = 60
WHITE = pygame.color.Color('#FFFFFF')
x, y = 20, 20
player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assests", "player1.png"))
player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (200, 200))
player_vel = 5

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
       # redraw_window()
        WIN.fill(WHITE)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        global x, y
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: y -= 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_s] and y < HEIGHT - 140: y += 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: x -= 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_d] and x < WIDTH - 120: x += 5
        
        WIN.blit(player, (x, y))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

    WIN.blit(player, (x, y))

    pygame.quit()
main()
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the current code? Please be specific with your question.

Comment: I've already found a sulution for this problem, But it was about making the player never goes off screen (like a border around the window/screen) so the player can be inside the window

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is:

```
        if pressed[pygame.K_w] and y-67 > 0: y -= 5 
        if pressed[pygame.K_s] and y < HEIGHT - 140: y += 5
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: x - 127 > 0 -= 5 # Try changing the numbers to get it right 
        if pressed[pygame.K_d] and x < WIDTH - 120: x += 5
```